# Jquery datatable unknow paramerter

Tags: datatables

I am facing an issue in jquery datatable i.e "DataTables warning: table id=paginatedTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

## my.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#paginatedTable').DataTable({
        "processing" : false,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "pageLength" : 1,
        ajax : {
            url : 'myurl',
             "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             "dataType": "json", 
            dataFilter : function(data) {

                return data; 
            },
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "orderId",sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            }, {
                "data" : "customer",sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            }, {
                "data" : "amount" ,sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            }, {
                "data" : "date", sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            }, {
                "data" : "status",sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            }, {
                "data" : "paymentModule",sDefaultContent: "n/a"
            } ]
        }
    });
});
```

### Data.json

```
{
    "draw": "1",
    "recordsFiltered": "2",
    "recordsTotal": "2",
    "data": [
        {
            "orderId": "2",
            "customer": "Rehan Afridi",
            "amount": "887",
            "date": "2018-06-22",
            "status": "DELIVERED",
            "paymentModule": "moneyorder"
        },
        {
            "orderId": "1",
            "customer": "aD SDAFASD",
            "amount": "887",
            "date": "2018-06-22",
            "status": "ORDERED",
            "paymentModule": "moneyorder"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the link to the error https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4. Check your '#paginatedTable' table structure.

Reading this error documentation I think your error can have two reasons:

> There is a colspan or rowspan in the tbody of the table, which is not supported by DataTables.

or

> Using columns or columnDefs you have specified more columns than there are in the HTML.